# Log4j 2 memory leak

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, log4j

Tomcat 10.0.6, log4j 2.14.1
При остановке сервера, пишутся следующие логи:

```
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.915 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@59402b8f]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent@7188af83]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.915 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6be968ce]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@7c37508a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.917 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@247310d0]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage@1033576a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.917 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@303cf2ba]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@76494737]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.921 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@59402b8f]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent@17fc391b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.921 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6be968ce]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter.PatternFormatter] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.DatePatternConverter$PatternFormatter@2b30a42c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13-Nov-2021 22:32:32.926 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [airline] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@247310d0]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ReusableSimpleMessage@609e8838]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Конфигурация log4j 2:

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="property_console">%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{1} - %msg%n</Property>
        <Property name="property_file">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%t] %logger{6} - %msg%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${property_console}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FileRolling" fileName="logs/log.txt" append="true" filePattern="logs/${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.txt">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${property_file}"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 K"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileRolling"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

В `pom.xml` подключил log4j2 вот так

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Это log4j не почистил за собой. Не думаю, что это серьёзная проблема.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Я новичок в web, хочу спросить. Вот такие утечки не могут вызвать в будущем проблем? Читал ещё про слушателя, который завершает работу логгера при уничтожении контекста. Но в servlet 3.0 писали, что его не нужно объявлять в web.xml.

Comment: Самые опасные утечки - это которые накапливаются со временем. В данном случае утекает несколько объектов на каждой остановке приложения. Если приложение останавливать и запускать, то теоретически эти объекты могут накапливаться, но скорость накапливания незначительна. При этом если рестартуется Томкат целиком, то ничего не накапливается. Даже если Томкат не рестартуется, то число утёкших объектов пропорционально числу потоков, а число потоков небесконечно, а очень даже конечно. Так что я бы не парился на счёт log4j.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ:)